# haproxy- setting up an TCP connection cache for an HTTP server

Tags: proxy, tcp, haproxy

I am trying to setup a local TCP connection cache to provide access to a remote HTTP server for multiple local applications.

I have started to configure haproxy to do this:

```
global
    log         /dev/log local0
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    timeout http-keep-alive 60000ms
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend  http-in
    option httplog
    bind  127.0.0.1:4443
    default_backend facebook

backend facebook
    server fb graph.facebook.com:443 maxconn 32 ssl verify none
```

which should allow me to use local proxy (http://localhost:4443) to talk to https://graph.facebook.com

And yes, it kind of works:

```
$ curl -4 -x http://127.0.0.1:4443 -vvv 'http://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAPvPqQIAjacV1whsrRfcchVVOXZAgi9ZC56HBVOh5PfI9IZBA12nAmsu9Q9Pznv1e6iZBsnbr4u2nCASnvZBGimBjdWErUXTRQetn0fdV0HLZB68tS0idelR35ybiWnehK5oec9dM9LxjRvFwTpuHSUkeA9nBAyFZBrGf4FcZAXuhT2uj5vjbvYkzupyi4mBFlBGfBEIjpeb'
```

However, when I tcpdump my local interface to see what is going to graph.facebook.com, I see that everytime I execute the above, a new TCP connection is created:

```
19:06:34.409962 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51970, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.1.80.42560 > 31.13.64.1.https: Flags [S], cksum 0xc6fe (correct), seq 1868596651, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 37375657 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:06:34.486631 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 86, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    31.13.64.1.https > 192.168.1.80.42560: Flags [S.], cksum 0xc226 (correct), seq 2991458091, ack 1868596652, win 13980, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 3177564556 ecr 37375657,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:06:34.486705 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51971, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.80.42560 > 31.13.64.1.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x262d (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 37375733 ecr 3177564556], length 0
19:06:34.486852 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51972, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 569)
    192.168.1.80.42560 > 31.13.64.1.https: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2730 (correct), seq 1:518, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 37375733 ecr 3177564556], length 517
19:06:34.578182 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 86, id 52940, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    31.13.64.1.https > 192.168.1.80.42560: Flags [.], cksum 0x2474 (correct), seq 1, ack 518, win 59, options [nop,nop,TS val 3177564650 ecr 37375733], length 0
...
```

Hence, my question: what did I do wrong here ? I would like my local haproxy server to keep open the TCP connections to graph.facebook.com as long as possible to be able to reuse them across multiple clients and requests but it looks like haproxy is creating and tearing down the TCP connections as needed despite option http-keep-alive.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [HAproxy documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt), concretely in the `1.1. The HTTP transaction model` section, says the following:

> By default HAProxy operates in a tunnel-like mode with regards to
>   persistent connections: for each connection it processes the first
>   request and forwards everything else (including additional requests)
>   to selected server. Once established, the connection is persisted both
>   on the client and server sides. Use "option http-server-close" to
>   preserve client persistent connections while handling every incoming
>   request individually, dispatching them one after another to servers,
>   in HTTP close mode. Use "option httpclose" to switch both sides to
>   HTTP close mode. "option forceclose" and "option
>   http-pretend-keepalive" help working around servers misbehaving in
>   HTTP close mode.

You've defined the `http-keep-alive` directive and have used none of the above described parameters, thus, you must be operating in tunnel mode (additionally, I have several HAproxy configurations very similar to yours and I can assure you it's working as the documentation says).

I think the culprit is the way you're using `curl` to test your configuration. You're passing it the `-x` flag which means you want to use the next parameter as a proxy, however, HAproxy already acts like it. So the request should be something like this:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:4443/v2.4/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAPvPqQ‌​IAjacV1whsrRfcchVVOXZAgi9ZC56HBVOh5PfI9IZBA12nAmsu9Q9Pznv1e6iZBsnbr4u2nCASnvZBGim‌​BjdWErUXTRQetn0fdV0HLZB68tS0idelR35ybiWnehK5oec9dM9LxjRvFwTpuHSUkeA9nBAyFZBrGf4Fc‌​ZAXuhT2uj5vjbvYkzupyi4mBFlBGfBEIjpeb
```

This way you're sending the request directly to HAproxy and not using HAproxy as a proxy (because it will behave this way itself).

Comment: I tried as per the suggestion but I get this: 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.facebook.com/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-FB-Debug: cPfFb58L4BkZsGHfyVA5TFuZ7b8cgcrY1jWYulBRk+YB22vv8Q9swKTA9jGUnxs58ZEoK1sxY7DqaOfmwyqQxQ==
< Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2015 07:44:02 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<

Comment: Probably some missing option to the `curl`. The best way to test this is accessing directly a web browser and opening up `http://your_haproxy_ip:4443/v2.4/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAPvPqQ‌​IAjacV1whsrRfcchVVOXZAgi9ZC56HBVOh5PfI9IZBA12nAmsu9Q9Pznv1e6iZBsnbr4u2nCASnvZBGim‌​BjdWErUXTRQetn0fdV0HLZB68tS0idelR35ybiWnehK5oec9dM9LxjRvFwTpuHSUkeA9nBAyFZBrGf4Fc‌​ZAXuhT2uj5vjbvYkzupyi4mBFlBGfBEIjpeb`

Comment: I wrote the following test python script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12519941/
so, I do get the right answer from the GET request but tcpdump still shows SYN+RST to facebook.com for each request http://paste.ubuntu.com/12519949/

Comment: To clarify the above comment, AFAICT, I see that haproxy does keep alive the server-side connection but only within the duration of the client-side TCP connection. i.e., it appears unable to keep the server-side connection open across multiple HTTP requests within multiple TCP connections.

Comment: That's strange. If the requests are made with less than 50 seconds of interval difference, they shouldn't be made over different TCP connections, they should use the same. The only suspicion left I have is that somehow the timeout client and server intervals are thwarting each other. Another interesting test would be trying a different website than facebook to see if it acts the same way.

Comment: same test with a simple http-only server, same result. 
Configuration: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12521224/ 
Test script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12521231/
tcpdump for two sequential requests on two separate tcp connections client-side triggers two separate tcp connections to server by haproxy: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12521242/

Comment: Interesting. What version are you using? I tried your example with minimal modifications and the tunnel keeps open for further requests.

Comment: verison: 1.5.14, FC22

Comment: I'm running 1.4.24 on Ubuntu 14.04, I wonder if that matters but as I said in my case it works as expected.

Comment: ok, well, I still did not find a solution to my problem but I feel that it is fair to award you the bounty given your extensive help in debugging this.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if I can help you with some additional test